# DBCC DBINFO incorrect dbi_dbccLastKnownGood

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to determine why `DBCC DBINFO` is returning different results than what is contained within the error log. Here's the setup:

Secondary Replica (read only access -- Asynchronous Commit AlwaysOn HA AG)

- Job ran at at `02/05/2018 09:00:00 PM` successfully, with a duration of `02:22:21`
- Only step in the job is `DBCC CHECKDB(myDB)`
- When I run `DBCC DBINFO('myDB') WITH TABLERESULTS` I see `dbi_dbccLastKnownGood  02/05/2018 00:00:40.113`. This should be `02/05/2018 11:22 PM`.
- When I check the error log, I see `02/05/2018 11:22:09 PM DBCC CHECKDB(myDB) executed by myAccount found 0 errors and repaired 0 errors. Elapsed time : 2 hours 22 minutes 9 seconds. Internal database snapshot has split point LSN ... and first LSN ...`

I decided to check the PRIMARY REPLICA where DBCC CHECKDB is also running (this is all set up by the vendor).

- Subplan ran at `02/05/2018 00:00:00 AM` successfully, with a duration of `02:14:40`
- When I run `DBCC DBINFO('myDB') WITH TABLERESULTS` I see `dbi_dbccLastKnownGood  02/05/2018 00:00:40.113` which is the same as the RoR but it should be `02/05/2018 02:15 AM`.
- When I check the error log, I see `02/05/2018 02:15:12 AM DBCC CHECKDB(myDB) WITH no_infomsgs exextued by myAccount found 0 error and repaired 0 errors. Elapsed time : 2 hours 14 minutes 40 seconds. Internal database snapshot has split point LSN ... and first LSN ...`

I can't figure out where this `DBCC DBINFO` results is coming from, and why it doesn't match the SQL logs. I set up a job to send me an alert when the dbi_dbccLastKnownGood is > 24 hours.

Any ideas? Let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: That flag can't be updated in a read only database.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik the DB isn't Read Only, it's configured for read only access. Sorry I wasn't clear. Regardless, the primary replica is also reporting the same, incorrect information which confuses me.

Comment: I want you to re-read what you just said very carefully.

Comment: Ok i'll elaborate. When I look at the DB on the secondary replica, under Options, the State = Database Read-Only = False. However, a user can't perform any DDL operations on this DB. So, perhaps i'm mistaken that read-only can be taken two different ways. But, you comment doesn't really help. The value continues to be updated on the secondary replica.

Comment: Here's an example @sp_BlitzErik, `DATABASEPROPERTYEX('myDB', 'Updateability')` returns READ_ONLY while `is_read_only` from `sys.databases` returns 0. Seems conflicting to me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> READ ONLY REPLICA (Asynchronous AlwaysOn HA AG)

Like Erik pointed out, AG Replicas are currently read only so it can't update the values here. Additionally, if it *did* update the values it would just be overwritten the next time anything was updated on the primary and the log block sent to the secondary.

> I decided to check the PRIMARY REPLICA where DBCC CHECKDB is also running
>
> •Subplan ran at 02/05/2018 00:00:00 AM successfully, with a duration of 02:14:40
>
> •When I run DBCC DBINFO('myDB') WITH TABLERESULTS I see dbi_dbccLastKnownGood  02/05/2018 00:00:40.113 which is the same as the RoR but it should be 02/05/2018 02:15 AM

The job started 2:14:40 ago, which is the time of the last known good checkdb - that's true. You started it then, it ran for 2 hours and 14 minutes +/- some agent stuffs. The times look fine to me, it's not like the job ran for 5 seconds and shows a last good of 6 hours ago.

I believe the issue is you expect the CHECKDB to show the good value at the end of the run versus being updated when it was executed. That shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Sean. I truly appreciate your help. You're right, I would have expected the lastGood to be when the command was finished versus initiated. I suppose one couldn't use DBCC DBINFO for this type of check if DBCC CHECKDB was being ran ONLY on the secondary replica. Cheers